# Downloading files from a website using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need to download all the files from (https://www.sec.gov/litigation/suspensions.shtml) given website. It has data from years 1995 to 2017 and inside each year there are multiple links for the files which need to be downloaded. Th files are in .pdf, .htm and .txt format. I tried scraping the data by seeing various tutorials but what I require to do is different from the usual web scraping tutorials. I used the following code but it did not serve my purpose. I am new to python and I am stuck here as to how to move forward. Can anyone please suggest what needs to be done.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.sec.gov/litigation/suspensions.shtml")
r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print soup.prettify()

links = soup.find_all("a")

for link in links:
        print "<a href= '%s'>%s</a>" %(link.get("href"), link.text)

g_data = soup.find_all("p", {"id": "archive-links"}) 
print g_data

for item in g_data:
    print item.text
```

Comment: what was the output of the your script

Comment: The quick and dirty way: just `grep -o` all urls like https://www.sec.gov/litigation/suspensions/2017/34-80766-o.pdf from the html, and use `wget` to download them all

Comment: @mtkilic - Hi, After using code by Denis, I am getting output as "Got links: set([])". I am unable t download the files. Can you help me make out what the problem is?

Comment: @RahulPipalia can you edit your question by adding full error message.

Comment: @mtkilic- I am to getting any error message. The code runs but gives the output as mentioned above. What could possibly be the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

That should do the work. Checked that on Python 3.6, but code should be Python2.7 compatible.
The main idea is to find link for every year and then grab all links to pdf, htm and txt files for each year.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def file_links_filter(tag):
    """
    Tags filter. Return True for links that ends with 'pdf', 'htm' or 'txt'
    """
    if isinstance(tag, str):
        return tag.endswith('pdf') or tag.endswith('htm') or tag.endswith('txt')


def get_links(tags_list):
    return [WEB_ROOT + tag.attrs['href'] for tag in tags_list]


def download_file(file_link, folder):
    file = requests.get(file_link).content
    name = file_link.split('/')[-1]
    save_path = folder + name

    print("Saving file:", save_path)
    with open(save_path, 'wb') as fp:
        fp.write(file)


WEB_ROOT = 'https://www.sec.gov'
SAVE_FOLDER = '~/download_files/'  # directory in which files will be downloaded

r = requests.get("https://www.sec.gov/litigation/suspensions.shtml")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

years = soup.select("p#archive-links > a")  # css selector for all <a> inside <p id='archive'> tag
years_links = get_links(years)

links_to_download = []
for year_link in years_links:
    page = requests.get(year_link)
    beautiful_page = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    links = beautiful_page.find_all("a", href=file_links_filter)
    links = get_links(links)

    links_to_download.extend(links)

# make set to exclude duplicate links
links_to_download = set(links_to_download)

print("Got links:", links_to_download)

for link in set(links_to_download):
    download_file(link, SAVE_FOLDER)
```

Comment: Hi @Denis Fetinin. It is giving me "Got links: set([])" and the files could not be downloaded. Is there some error?

Comment: @RahulPipalia, I actually run that script and it downloaded files just fine. What Python version are you running? What is the beautifulsoup version do you use? I would try to run script with a debugger a check where it fails to pars links. Otherwise, you can put a lot of `print` statements to see what's happening.

Comment: @ Denis Fetinin- I am using python 2.7.10. I am using beautifulsoup4. I will try to run again and see if it works.